# How do I correctly use OperatorApplied?

Tags: functional-style

Starting with

```
ClearAll[f, list]
list = {"a", "the"}
f[s_, n1_, n2_] := {s, n1, n2}
```

Then

```
f[list, 20, 10]
```

Gives

```
{{"a", "the"}, 20, 10}
```

And after

```
f2 = f[#,20,10] &
```

Then

```
f2[list]
```

Again gives

```
{{"a", "the"}, 20, 10}
```

All is good. Now I want to define an operator op3

```
op3 = OperatorApplied[f,SOMETHING][20][10]
```

So that

```
op3[list]
```

Gives

```
{{"a", "the"}, 20, 10}
```

My question is what replaces SOMETHING in the code above? I've studied the documentation to OperatorApplied and CurryApplied, tried many alternatives, but cannot "grok" an answer for my application. (Of which the above is a simplification.)

Comment: Does `op3 = OperatorApplied[f, {3, 1, 2}][20][10]` do what you want?

Comment: DId you miss some code?  Is your `f2[#,20,10] &` line supposed to be `f2=f[#,20,10] &` ?

Comment: Thanks Edmund. I have to figure out how to copy and paste multiple from Mathematica into these posts. Fixed it.

Comment: Thanks Carl. Your code works. It's an answer. If you could clue me on the meaning of {3,1,2}. I would appreciate it. My understanding is 3 items in the list {3, 1, 2} means f takes three arguments.And then, is this right?. The first slot in f is filled by the 3 argument in the "curried" call, the second slot in f is filled by the 1 argument in the curried call, the third slot in f is filled by the 2 argument in the curried call. By curried call, I mean the op3[list] call.   Is there a good way to think about this?

Comment: Out of curiosity: What is the advantage of defining such an operator as opposed to the function solution?